# how to display product with category name on cms page in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category

I have a one cms page with name stock list and i want to show here all the product with the corresponding category name above it. like this

category 1

product1 product2 proudct3

category2 
proudct1 product2 product3

I tried

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="8" template="catalog/product/featured.phtml"}}
```

but this will only show the product from a specific category not does not print the name of the category

I have around 50 category so it is not a good practice for me to do this type of coding again and again to show product from all the category.

so I think that one solution for this is to call the view.phtml file which is used to show product on category page. but i don't know the code how to call that file on cms page. so can any one help me in this or give me the better idea for this problem

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where your template file `featured.phtml` is coming from, as it seems not the be a Magento core file.
But you can use your own template file (other then `featured.phtml`) and make sure it outputs the category name of the called category (referenced by `category_id="8"`).
Copy your `featured.phtml` and add a line to output the category's name. As your block type is `catalog/product_list` look at the file `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php` to get a clue how you can achive this. As you can see in line 79 you can get the referenced category ID by `$this->getCategoryId()`.
So a

```
<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getCategoryId())->getName() ?>
```

would do the trick inside you template file. The layout is up to you.
This is from Vinai's reply on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534236/how-to-get-the-category-name-from-list-phtml-in-magento